# Prove $D(E)=\{(x,y):x-y\in E\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$, prove $D(E)=\{(x,y):x-y\in E\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Hint: $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Could you please show more details? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. $D(E)=f^{-1}(E)$.

Comment: I have a idea.Set a invertible mapping from D(E) to E*R: (x,y)→(x-y,y).

Comment: What about $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous and hence measurable. Therefore, since $E$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}$, also $f^{-1}(E)=D(E)$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @StefanHansen I understand it has been several years, but I believe your idea is not the correct. If $E$ is Borel, then $f^{-1})(E)$ will be Lebesgue measurable. But if $E$ is Lesbesgue measurable (and not Borel), then $f^{-1}(E)$ is not necessarily Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @Waldon: It depends on what the OP means when he says that $E$ should be measurable. I had assumed it meant Borel measurable but if he meant Lebesgue measurable, then a little more is needed. However, we can only speculate about what the OP meant since he never followed up on my comment.

Comment: @StefanHansen I'm confused by this, since I would think that whatever we mean by "measurable" it would be the same in both parts.  So if "$E$ is measurable" means Borel, then "$D(E) is measurable" should also mean Borel, right?  And likewise for Lebesgue?  I know we're just speculating about OP's meaning still, but if we assume throughout a consistent meaning of "measurable" then your argument needs no further adjustment right?